# Is scripting supposed to be this hard and annoying?

Tags: python, scripting

I've been trying to make simple tool for blender for a couple of months now and my experience with scripting so far was nightmarish. I really want to continue working with blender but if it continues to be like this I'll go mental. I'm hoping that after reading through my issues you can help clear out some of these uncertainties.

I got a problem with 2 things in particular:

Is there supposed to be so much trial and error? I literally can't write a single working line of code without a ton of guesswork, changing stuff at random and hoping it's gonna work this time. I often try doing something in the viewport, then copy the line of code that pops up in the INFO tab and then experiment with it in a separate text file to find out how it actually works. I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to do it like this, but I don't know of any other way.

Is documentation terrible or am I missing something? I'm talking about this: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html
Is this even the right documentation for addon development? Seriously, almost none of the expressions are actually explained e.g.:

"bpy.context.selected_objects"
sequence of bpy.types.Object

Here's what it doesn't tell you:
it's not a sequence of objects in order in which they were selected as you may expect
, the first element in the array is always changed to the active object
and after some testing I also found out that order in which you ADD OBJECTS TO THE SCENE matters here as well!
Why is none of this mentioned anywhere?

Or even worse is this one:

"bpy.context.objects_in_mode"
Type
sequence of bpy.types.Object

In what mode? I can't just google "Blender 2.8 what is "in_mode" in bpy.context.objects_in_mode".

many of their names don't even make sense, like this one:

"hide_select"
Bone is able to be selected

Like why is it named "hide" when it should instead be called "bone_selectable" or something?

On top of that I'm having a hard time finding up-to-date ( 2.8 ) resources for scripting. If you know of any pls let me know.

Again, I really want to continue working with blender, but most the time I'm just stuck, trying things at random and hoping one of them works. And it's not like I'm new to programming either, I'm perfectly comfortable writing code in UE4 that always does what I want it to do without all this mess I have to go through scripting in blender.

If anyone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong I would be forever thankful for that.

Comment: IMHO the API is pretty nice compared to others, not sure what you're after though... In general: using the "Info area" and copy some lines is not a good idea since it just records the operators called by the user or when changing a property. I'd recommend use the python console to eliminate some guesswork, have a look into the python templates that come with blender and read through other add-ons and scripts. If you are familiar with python it shouldn't be hard to understand the principles. You can always ask a *specific* question here, or even a broader one on blenderartist or devtalk....

Comment: Your post made me laugh a little. Many coders keep a rubber ducky by their desk as kind of a a "stress ball" because debugging is so infuriating that they need something to crush/throw from time to time. You also picked a unique time to learn to code in blender, as it has undergone several version revisions recently (even between 2.80 and 2.83), with some code commands staying the same and others changing. Many tutorials do not reflect these subtle differences. My best advice is to use the most current version of the official docs as a reference, and use the console as brockmann suggested.

Comment: I have to agree with you that a general, Plain-English overview of the logical structure of the API would be very helpful. It has, and still is, taking me an IMO unnecessarily long time, and a lot  of reverse-engineering, to figure out how things fit together. Have a look at @dr. Sybren 's extensive and patient [Scripting for Artists](https://cloud.blender.org/p/scripting-for-artists/) course, even if you're not one, and it may occasionally be too dilute for you. The videos can be sampled on YouTube.

Comment: I've been struggling to make a simple frustum with an upper lip and it's been riddled with headaches:
1. Blender doesn't save selections so that you can call them as a command...why? one would think that would be basic.
2. I have to use spaghetti code to select specific edges by jumping back and forth between object and edit mode and even then the vertex indexing is RANDOM! I finally find the selection I want, I run it and then boom! It selects the wrong vertices spontaneously.
There's a lot more, but blender scripting is awful and not fit for purpose. It needs to be redone.

Answer (score 1):

Hi 1st of all I would recommend using https://code.visualstudio.com/download (Visual Studio code as it has a ton of more features that will help you to script and create addons for blender)

Once you download that I would also recommend using the blender addon development by Jacques Lucke which you can search for it on the marketplace. Once you have done that you need to check this out https://github.com/nutti/fake-bpy-module.

Or you can just open the terminal in vscode and type in pip install pip install fake-bpy-module-2.80

Also one last here is the link to blender addon development tutorial (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check all of these out.